# Iterate through tuple values python

Tags: python, tuples, loops

I have a list like
`[(1, 3), (6, 7)]`
and a string
`'AABBCCDD'`
I need to get the result `AABCD`.
I know I can get the integers form the tuple with `nameOfTuple[0][0]` yielding 1.
I also know that I can get the chars form the string with `nameOfString[0]` yielding A.
My question is, how do I iterate through two arguments in the tuple, in order to save the integers (to a list maybe) and then get the chars from the string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
In [1]: l = [(1, 3), (6, 7)]

In [2]: s = 'AABBCCDD'

In [3]: ''.join(s[start-1:end] for (start,end) in l)
Out[3]: 'AABCD'
```

Here, pairs of indices from `l` are assigned to `start` and `end`, one pair at a time. The relevant portion of the string is then extracted using `s[start-1:end]`, yielding a sequence of strings. The strings are then merged using `join()`.

Comment: Thx m8, this was just the kind of answer I was looking for. I thought, that you had to make a "double iteration" through the tuples, to keep track of them.